# Flutter align widget horizontaly and verticaly

Tags: flutter, dart, view, position, alignment

I am working on a Flutter project. I'm trying to create a widget like the image below and I can't manage to do it.

[image]

So what I'm trying to do, is to create a widget with a `Text` at the top left (the size of this widget is not constant and depends on the text in it).
I'm trying to align 2 other widgets with the `Text`:

- The `Widget 1` is aligned horizontaly and centered with the `Text` widget and at its right with no space between
- The `Widget 2`'s right edge is aligned verticaly with the `Text` widget's right edge, and is positioned under it (and there is no space between the 2 widgets).

I tried to implement this with `Column` and `Row` widgets or with a `GridView` but I couldn't manage to do so.

Also the overall size of this custom widget has to be shrinked.

Does someone know how to do something like that ?

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you to use staggeredGridView.. just look for it in dart packages

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 300,
      color: Colors.grey[200],
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                flex: 2,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.orange,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but the size of the text is not fixed therefore the propotions are not always going to be 2:1 or whatever constant number :/

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the width and height, you can use media query or fractional sized box widget or by adding padding/margin to the text widget.
Refer other Flutter responsive ui  https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive